# Is there a way to Boost.Assign a ptr_vector?

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, ptr-vector

Usually like this:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
vector<int> v;
v += 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Except for a:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
boost::ptr_vector<int> v;
```

If you need to know the reason; I'm using `ptr_vector` instead of `vector` only so I don't have to delete elements, but I need to initialize it using Boost.Assign as I want the `ptr_vector` to be `const` (can't use `push_back()` or `pop_back()` anywhere else in code.)

Thanks in advance for you answers, it's possible I'm using the wrong container type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Boost.Assigns [`ptr_list_of()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#ptr_list_of):

```
#include <boost/assign/ptr_list_of.hpp>

// ...
const boost::ptr_vector<int> pv = boost::assign::ptr_list_of<int>(1)(2)(3);
```